# Did Parashurama cede all his powers to end the confrontation with Rama in the Ramayana?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, rama, parashurama

The two Ramas have a confrontation and at the end Parashruma says

> But I triumphed over matchless realms of heavens with my ascesis, oh, Rama, you may hash them up with that irreversible arrow... let there be no time-lag

he seems to be relinquishing all his powers to end the confrontation   And if so - how is he a formidable warrior in Mahabharata also?

Answer (score 3):

Rama did take his power from Parashurama but he regained it by bathing in the tirtha of Bhrigu as explained in [Vana Parva Section XCIX](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03099.htm). Lomasa told Pandavas that by bathing in the tirtha of Bhrigu, he will regain his energy taken away from Duryodhana like how Parashurama regained his might.

> And behold there, O Yudhisthira, the tirtha of Bhrigu that is celebrated over the three worlds and adored, O king, by great Rishis. B**athing here, Rama (of Bhrigu's race) regained his might, which had been taken away from him (by Dasaratha's son).** Bathing here, **O son of Pandu, with thy brothers and Krishna, thou wilt certainly regain that energy of thine** that hath been taken away by Duryodhana, **even as Rama regained his that had been taken away by Dasaratha's son in hostile encounter."**

Parashurama got his powers back which explains why he was still a formidable warrior in Mahabharata.

Comment: Parashurama regaining his powers is an interpolation. It has been removed by BORI. This event is not mentioned in the entire southern manuscripts, Kashmir manuscripts and older Devanagiri manuscripts.